# Calculate next scheduled time based on cron spec

Tags: python, algorithm, cron, scheduler

What's an efficient way to calculate the next run time of an event given the current time and a cron spec?

I'm looking for something other than "loop through every minute checking if it matches spec".

Examples of specs might be:

- Every month, on the 1st and 15 at 15:01
- At 10,20,30,40,50 mins past the hour every hour

Python code would be lovely but psuedo code or high level description would also be appreciated.

[Update] Assume the spec is already parsed and is in some reasonable format.

Comment: I've done something like this, and found it tricky to get right (and my possible "specs" are a subset of yours).  I just did it with some datetime calcs and functions for each `type` of spec.  I'm interested if someone has a better answer (solution will probably be use library: x)

Comment: Can you give an example of the spec format?

Comment: [Later.js](https://github.com/bunkat/later) is a javascript library that does just this. It is able to parse a Cron expression and then calculate future occurrences of the schedule. It's algorithm isn't very fancy, but it does the job. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just looking at it, I think you need to:

- parse the chron spec to five arrays containing acceptable values for each field;
- parse 'now' to a value for each field;
- in order of minute, hour, {day-of-month OR day-of-week}, month-of year: find the lowest array value that matches or exceeds the current value, correcting for carry.

*I don't know how to handle day-of-week and day-of-month simultaneously; I am sure there is a way, but on the other hand I don't think I've ever seen a spec that actually specified both.  I think it would be sufficient to write a handler for either and throw an error if you receive both.*

**Edit:** apparently if day-of-week and day-of-month are both specified, it is supposed to fire on **both** - ie if the rule is '15th, Wednesday' it will fire on every 15th **and** every Wednesday.

The croniter package does what you want:

```
import croniter
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
sched = '1 15 1,15 * *'    # at 3:01pm on the 1st and 15th of every month
cron = croniter.croniter(sched, now)

for i in range(4):
    nextdate = cron.get_next(datetime.datetime)
    print nextdate
```

prints

```
2011-01-15 15:01:00
2011-02-01 15:01:00
2011-02-15 15:01:00
2011-03-01 15:01:00
```

although it would be nice if it were written as an actual iterator. Maybe I've got my next project ;-)

Comment: Nice find with croniter, much thanks. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anyone drops a fantastic algorithm on us.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used your code to make it work, but I needed to run it as an EXE file so I compiled it into one using py2exe. For anyone wanting to use it you can download it from here: http://www.toughtomato.com/cron2NextDate/. Usage example: cron2NextDate.exe "0 15 1 * *"

Comment: Unfortunately `croniter` only evaluates in UTC time. I have to adjust my expressions to UTC time