# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' - Print next crontab scheduled job with croniter - stdout - Python

Tags: python, cron, attributeerror

I need to read the contents of the `/etc/crontab` file.

Right now I have this:

```
import croniter
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()


def main():

    f = open("/etc/crontab","r")
    f1 = f.readlines()
    cron = croniter.croniter(f1, now)
    for x in f1:
        cron.get_next(datetime.datetime)
        print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I want is to print the next time a task will run, based on what's defined on my crontab file, I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7399453/2089267), however I need to actually read this from a file (crotab file that is) then print it to stdout.

Right now it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cron.py", line 17, in <module>
main()
File "cron.py", line 11, in main
cron = croniter.croniter(f1, now)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 92, in __init__
self.expanded, self.nth_weekday_of_month = self.expand(expr_format)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 464, in expand
expressions = expr_format.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any ideas on this? I'm very new to `croniter`, there's also `python-crontab` but haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`croniter` handles a single cron-expression. You should have it inside the loop, and apply it to each row individually:

```
for x in f1:
    cron = croniter.croniter(x, now) # Here!
    cron.get_next(datetime.datetime)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thank You very much, sorry, just a question, now it throws me `croniter.croniter.CroniterBadCronError: Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iteratorexpression.`